# bottom navigation bar flutter shape rounded

Tags: flutter, shapes

I have a bottom navigation bar in Flutter with a floating action button. The problem is that the shape is too angular and it needs to be more rounded. I have manually moved the shape to the middle, but I can't get the rounded shape as desired in the picture. Below you can see the code for the shape in the ShapeDecoration.

[Picture of the Bottom Navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFpdR.png)

```
class MyBorderShape extends ShapeBorder {
  MyBorderShape();

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.zero;

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) => null;

  double holeSize = 70;

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    print(rect.height);
    return Path.combine(
      PathOperation.difference,
      Path()
        ..addRRect(
            RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, Radius.circular(rect.height / 2.5)))
        ..close(),
      Path()
        ..addOval(Rect.fromCenter(
            center: rect.center.translate(0, -rect.height / 2),
            height: holeSize,
            width: holeSize))
        ..close(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [animated_bottom_navigation_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_bottom_navigation_bar) plugin.
Code:-

```
Scaffold(
   body: Container(), // your page body over here
   floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      //params
   ),
   floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
   bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBottomNavigationBar(
    elevation: 0,
    icons: const [
      Icons.home,
      Icons.home,
      Icons.home,
      Icons.home,
    ],
    activeIndex: currentIndex,
    gapLocation: GapLocation.center,
    notchSmoothness: NotchSmoothness.smoothEdge,//for more curve use NotchSmoothness.verySmoothEdge
    leftCornerRadius: 0,
    rightCornerRadius: 0,
    onTap: onTapChangePage,
    //other params
  ),
);
```